# Change value when user input value

Tags: reactjs

I have collected the code used to convert units in CSS When the user changes the value in the input, the inputs also change. How does the below code work? in function NumberInput where did I go wrong, please show me! I'm a newbie to react :D

Code that executes on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-moon-08ooyn?file=/src/css-units.tsx).

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ListType } from './types'

export default function CssUnits() {
  const [em, setEm] = React.useState<number>(1)
  ...

  const emHandler = (val: number) => {
    setRem(val)
    setPx(val * 16)
    setPercent(val * 100)
    setPt(val * 12)
  }
  ...

  const List: ListType[] = [
    {
      label: 'EM',
      description: 'Relative to the font-size of the element',
      state: em,
      onChange: (val) => {
        emHandler(val || 0)
      },
    },
    ...
  ]

  function NumberInput({ key, value, variant, label, description, onChange, precision }) {
    return (
        <div key={key} className="my-8">
            <div className="text-xl font-medium">{label} <span className="text-sm text-gray-400">({description})</span></div>
            <input type='text' value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="my-4">
      <h2>CSS Units converter</h2>
        {List.map((item, index) => {
          const decimalPoint = item.state.toString().split('.')
          return (
            <NumberInput
              key={index}
              value={item.state}
              variant='default'
              label={item.label}
              description={item.description}
              onChange={item.onChange}
              precision={decimalPoint[1] ? decimalPoint[1].length : 0}
            />
          )
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you share an executable sample of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: @MajidM.  Here is the code that executes on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-moon-08ooyn?file=/src/css-units.tsx). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChange` function in `NumberInput` pass `event` to the `item.onChange`. So, you need to change this part of your code:

```
 onChange={item.onChange}
```

to:

```
onChange={(e) => item.onChange(e.target.value)}
```

for passing correct value!

Also, in every handler you should set current handler value to see current input value changes simultaneously.

You can refer to this `codesandbox`:

[image: Edit pensive-shape-rpdxwq]